# How to scrape a data table that has multiple pages using selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm extracting NBA stats from my yahoo fantasy account. Below is the code that I made in jupyter notebook using selenium. Each page shows 25 players and a total of 720 players. I did a for loop that will scrape players in increments of 25 instead of one by one.

```
for k in range (0,725,25):
Players = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/div/div/a')
Team_Position = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class= "Fz-xxs"]')
Games_Played = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[7]/div')
Minutes_Played = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[11]/div')
FGM_A = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[12]/div')
FTM_A = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[14]/div')
Three_Points = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[16]/div')
PTS = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[17]/div')
REB = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[18]/div')
AST = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[19]/div')
ST = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[20]/div')
BLK = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[21]/div')
TO = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[22]/div')

NBA_Stats = []
for i in range(len(Players)):
    players_stats = {'Name': Players[i].text,
                    'Position': Team_Position[i].text,
                    'GP': Games_Played[i].text,
                    'MP': Minutes_Played[i].text,
                    'FGM/A': FGM_A[i].text,
                    'FTM/A': FTM_A[i].text,
                    '3PTS': Three_Points[i].text,
                    'PTS': PTS[i].text,
                    'REB': REB[i].text,
                    'AST': AST[i].text,
                    'ST': ST[i].text,
                    'BLK': BLK[i].text,
                    'TO': TO[i].text}
driver.get('https://basketball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/nba/28951/players?status=ALL&pos=P&cut_type=33&stat1=S_AS_2021&myteam=0&sort=AR&sdir=1&count=' + str(k))
```

The browser will go page by page after it's done. I print out the results. It only scrape 1 player. What did I do wrong?

[A picture of my codes and printing the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2FPo.png)

Comment: put in some delays with `time.sleep()` (not preferred) or with seleniums explicit wait. What might be happening is the code runs too fast and is trying to get an element that is not there anymore, or hasn't rendered yet.

Comment: another thing I would change here is it looks like you are parsing `<table>` tags. Use pandas `.read_html()`. It's far easier to use

Comment: I also have a strong suspicion we can get this data via an api

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what the issue here is without looking at the original page (can you provide a URL?), however looking at this:

```
next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id = "yui_3_18_1_1_1636840807382_2187"]')
```

"1636840807382" looks like a Javascript timestamp, so I would guess that the reference you've got hardcoded there is dynamically generated, so the element "yui_3_18_1_1_1636840807382_2187" no longer exists.

Comment: I did notice the element will change if it goes to the next page. So I'm looking for an element-by-link text which is 'Next 25'.